# PayPal Express Checkout Custom Field

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal and making a PayPal Express Checkout plug at this moment, but I want the custom field in IPN messages being filled.

```
'CUSTOM' => $this->ordercode,
'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM' => $this->ordercode,
```

The above part is being sent in the DoExpressCheckoutPayment and SetExpressCheckout part but I need to be sure that "custom" field is being filled when an IPN message is being sent to the site to check the payment state.
(I can set this custom field when testing IPN, but is the API filling this also? Just like the normal PayPal IPN)

Or do I have to use another field that can be checked in the IPN message so I can process the order if something went wrong on the return of the customer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, passing `PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM` will make its way to the `custom` field in IPN messages.

Instead of using the IPN simulator, I'd suggest creating a couple Sandbox test accounts through https://developer.paypal.com/ and going through the end-to-end checkout flow, including Express Checkout API calls and IPN messages.